# Class as parameter in python __init__

Tags: python, class, arguments

I am struggling to implement Card deck on python.I have two classes **Rank** and **Suit**.
And now i have to implement new class Card, which takes as parameters two OTHER CLASSES.

`class Card(object):
def __init__(self, rank, suit)
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit`

> When i try to do 
>   `card = Card(*parameters*)` and afterwards `card.rank` must return `<__main__.Ace object at 0x7f2632ed5890>`
>
> Ace  is the name of the card.My code returns  `<class '__main__.Ace'>`. And after CARD takes two classes as arguments i think i don't have to inherit Rank and SUit, do I?

Comment: No you do not. But what is your question? Can you show a bit more of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate a rank object  in the `__init__` method of the Card class,try the following.It would create an object of class rank and an object of class suit (assuming rank and suit do not take any parameters).

```
    class Card(object):
        def __init__(self, rank, suit): 
            self.rank = rank() 
            self.suit = suit()
```

Alternatively you can create the rank and suit objects outside the Card class and pass them to the `__init__` method

I tried the following and got the output `<__main__.Rank instance at 0xb7226dac>`

```
class Card(object):

    def __init__(self,rank,suit):
         self.rank=rank()
         self.suit=suit()

class Rank:
    pass

class Suit:
    pass


def main():
    c=Card(Rank,Suit)
    print c.rank

main()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user253956, Yes but the OP is already passing in the `rank` and `suit` objects and your second suggesting is precisely what the OP is doing anyways.

Comment: @Manik Tharaka, thank you. This is exactly what i am trying to do. I forgot to mention it, but i also tryied this kind of ` __init__`, but `card.rank` still returns class and not an instance.

Comment: It worked, thank you! And do you have any idea how can i make Card class immutable I try `def __setattr__(cls, attr, value):
                raise AttributeError ("Cannot assign attributes to this class")` but it is not working. Thanks again